# sending command to terminal from java with space in it

Tags: java, linux, bash, runtime.exec

I am working on a java program, where i need to invoke a bash script that takes a string as an argument. so I've written the code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./script \"message send\"");
```

but it seems as if the terminal isn't recognizing the quotes (") as quotes, and referring to the term "message send" as two arguments: "message and send", and so the script is not invoked properly.

anyone have any idea what i can do?

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` with commands would be easier. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder(java.lang.String...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform this by using ProcessBuilder.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
p.command("cmd_to_run", "args_if_any");
p.start();
```